# How to use RSA in .net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I try to encrypt a file with `RSA`, but it don't have the `toXmlString()` and `fromXmlString` method. how to use `RSA` class in .net core ?
And I want to encrypt with private key and decrypt with public key ,so others can only read this file but can't generate this file ， Is that possible ?

Comment: Can't you use the other methods that are avaiable?

Comment: all example that I find online , they all use the `fromXmlString` method . Can you show me another way?

Comment: You can use an extension like this one: https://gist.github.com/Jargon64/5b172c452827e15b21882f1d76a94be4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the `ToXmlString` and `FromXmlString` methods are not available, `ImportParameters(RSAParameters)` and `ExportParameters(bool)` are.

If you have existing XML formatted values that you need to continue to read, the XML format of the keys isn't very interesting:

Public only:

```
<RSAKeyValue>
  <Modulus>[base64-encoded value]</Modulus>
  <Exponent>[base64-encoded value]</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

Public+Private:

```
<RSAKeyValue>
  <Modulus>[base64-encoded value]</Modulus>
  <Exponent>[base64-encoded value]</Exponent>
  <P>[base64-encoded value]</P>
  <Q>[base64-encoded value]</Q>
  <DP>[base64-encoded value]</DP>
  <DQ>[base64-encoded value]</DQ>
  <InverseQ>[base64-encoded value]</InverseQ>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

(where each named XML element maps to the field of the same name on the `RSAParameters` struct)

Otherwise you can/should use whatever serialization mechanism is the best suited for you and your application.

Comment: I create my own `ToXMlString` and `FromXmlString` with  `exportParameters` and `ImportParameters` , it work fine ,but that can not use priviate key to encrypto and public key to decrypto,  any Suggestions?

Comment: @John A private key can encrypt, since it has the public, but a public key cannot decrypt. Using the private key to prove authenticity is called signing, so perhaps you want SignData and VerifyData, as opposed to Encrypt and Decrypt.

Comment: Perhaps you realize that I want to write a license file, that license is a Encrypted  xml file( binary formate ) contains some necessary information . My application need that information to startup and do something. So I really need to encrypt and decrypt that, currently i use AES to encrypt that file, but if someone decompile my application, they will get the AES key , so they can easily generate any license thay want .

Comment: This is straying from the original question, perhaps you need a new one. A license file is usually not encrypted, but rather signed. { License: { User: John, Serial: 123456789 }, Signature: (binary/base64 blob) }.Then you build a binary form of license (e.g. UTF-8 User concat serial) and call rsaPublic.VerifyData(data, license.Signature, ...).  But .NET (Core or Framework) does not allow private encrypt + public decrypt except for RSA signing.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you get less when using pure .net core:

> In the end this means you can build on .NET Core today, and expect
>   more features to light up later, so things will get easier as time
>   goes on. Whether you want to be an early adopter **with the less
>   featured framework now**, **or jump in later when more features have been
>   added** and the third party eco-system has caught up is going to be a
>   (tough) decision that we all have to make on your own.

You will have them available if you target the full .net framework in .net core.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {}
  }
}
```

They won't be available with for example:

```
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
```